# Error if inside value of input in echo

Tags: php

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='codigo' value='". if($acao == 'editar'){ echo $dados['codigo']}."'>"
```

I don't know how to do to put an **if** inside the **echo**.

Comment: you'll need to use a ternary instead inside the echo, and please use english

Comment: Даже не знаю, что сказать... Учи синтаксис

Comment: I translated your question to English. Eu traduzi sua pergunta para o Inglês.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` is a directive and cannot be used in string concatenation because it does not return a value, you *can* however use a ternary operator like so:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='codigo' value='". ($acao == 'editar' ? $dados['codigo'] : '') ."'>";
```

as PHP knows for a fact that the operator has to return a value that it can concatenate, just like functions, if it can *return* a value it can be used in concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize a variable to use in place because it looks more readable.

```
if($acao == 'editar')
   $codigo =  $dados['codigo'];
else
   $codigo = "";

echo "<input type='hidden' name='codigo' value='$codigo'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='codigo' value='". ($acao == 'editar') ? $dados['codigo'] : "" ."'>"
```

Or, if this does not seem to be very good to read, use a variable:

```
$result = ($acao == 'editar') ? $dados['codigo'] : "";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='codigo' value='$result'>"
```

I think this last option easier to read, but it is a matter of taste.